# pytest mocking .count() and .find() functions of MongoReplicaSetClient object

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pymongo, pytest

I have a script called commons.py which contains some most commonly used functions.

In my main script, I am creating a mongo connection object:

```
db_ob = commons.db_connection()
```

db_connection returns a MongoReplicaSetClient connection object.

how to write test cases for my below function??

```
def check_entries():
    try:
        db_ob = commons.db_connection()
    except:
        print('Unable to connect to db!!')
        return False
    db_name = 'my_db_name'
    collection_name = 'my_collection_name'
    db_data = db_ob[db_name][collection_name].find()
    if db_data.count() == 0:
        print('No entries found in the collection!')
        return False
    return True
```

I can mock my db_connection function but I am having problem mocking the .count() and .find() functions.

Answer (score 2):

Example with mocking the cursor to test the case when the result set is empty:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client import MongoReplicaSetClient
from pymongo.cursor import Cursor
import testee


def test_empty_result_set():
    db_data_mock = MagicMock(spec=Cursor)()  # 1
    db_data_mock.count.return_value = 0  # 2
    db_conn_mock = MagicMock(spec=MongoReplicaSetClient)()  # 3
    db_conn_mock.__getitem__().__getitem__().find.return_value = db_data_mock
    with patch('commons.db_connection', return_value=db_conn_mock):  # 4
        assert not testee.check_entries()  # 5
```

Details:

1. `MagicMock(spec=Cursor)` returns a class that mimics `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` class. `db_data_mock` is an instance of this mock class.
2. `db_data_mock.count.return_value = 0` mocks the `count` method so it always returns zero.
3. Next two lines: create a mock instance for the `pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client.MongoReplicaSetClient` (same way as in 1.) and connect the cursor mock instance to it so that `find()` method always returns `db_data_mock` instance we created before.
4. Last, replace the `commons.db_connection` function with the mocked one that returns our `MongoReplicaSetClient` mock object.
5. All preparations done; do the actual test.

---

#### Update: a test that does not use `unittest` was requested in the comments

If, for some strange "purity" reason, you don't want to touch the `unittest` code, you have to either find a replacement library for that, or write the mocks yourself. `pytest` does not offer mocking functionality out of the box. The example above without `unittest` could look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import testee


class CursorMock:

    def count(self):
        return 0


class ConnectionMock:

    def find(self):
        return CursorMock()


class MongoReplicaSetClientMock:

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return defaultdict(ConnectionMock)


def db_connection_mock(*args, **kwargs):
    return MongoReplicaSetClientMock()


def test_empty_result_set(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(commons, 'db_connection', db_connection_mock)
    assert not testee.check_entries()
```

Instead of `unittest.mock.patch` the [`monkeypatch` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) was used.

Note that although there are some plugins for `pytest` that offer mocking functionality (for example, [`pytest-mock`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock)), most that I know of are just handy wrappers around `unittest.mock` and still use that under the hood.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response but I am using pytest and not unittest. Would it be possible to do the same using pytest? I do not want to write some cases in pytest and some in unittest to maintain uniformity.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the difference between the two. `pytest` mainly replaces `unittest` in test collection, test execution, test signatures (functions vs classes + classmethods) and assertions. In fact, the test above was written using `pytest`; it won't be even recognized by `unittest`.

Comment: However, `pytest` does not provide a replacement for mocking functionality. The only feature available out of the box is [monkeypatching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html), this can be viewed as a (pretty limited) replacement for `unittest.mock.patch`, but there is nothing to replace mocks/stubs. If, for some reason, you don't want to use `unittest` mocks, you will have to write your own mock/stub classes, but it is contraproductive: you have to write and maintain a lot more testing code than you have to.

Comment: But I will update the answer with a test that does not import `unittest` if this is what you aim for.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Since the db_connection function is returning an object, I made my mock function return an object too with the required functions inbuilt.

I went around making a class with the required functions and returning the object in the desired format.

Based upon various cases(successful/unsuccesful connection, various values of count etc), there could be several mock functions.

```
def mock_db_connection_success(*args, **kwargs):
    """Function to mock successful db connection."""
    class ReturnClass(object):
        """."""
        @staticmethod
        def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
            """."""
            pass

        # @staticmethod
        def find(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """."""
            return self

        @staticmethod
        def count(*args, **kwargs):
            """."""
            return 1
    class_ob = ReturnClass()
    return {"my_db_name": {"my_collection_name": class_ob}}


@mock.patch('my_script.commons.db_connection', side_effect=mock_db_connection_success)
def test_function(*args, **kwargs):
    """Test Function."""
    # use the function here
```

I also found an implementation of the same using a python library: [flexmock](https://flexmock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Using the library, we need not write the complete definition for a class and can be done with the bare minimum definitions. It provides a lot of help in writing various cases faster.